# Python selenium title that contains a specific text

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to check the prospectus website until the file contains the specific number, the example number is '460'.

First I check website whose title contains'투자설명서'(prospectus), then in the prospectus, there will be a series number for the transaction on the top of main page.

Then I would like to check if the number is 460, but the latest series in the page is 461, I would like to close that wrong page and keep search until find the series which is 460, but I cannot achieve that.

I cannot let the website click next page to keep search...

I tried:

```
url = 'https://dart.fss.or.kr/dsab007/main.do?option=corp'
driver.get(url)
cpny_name_input = driver.find_element_by_id("textCrpNm")
cpny_name_input.clear()
cpny_name_input.send_keys("롯데카드")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchForm"]/div[1]/div/ul/li/div[3]/a').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchForm"]/div[1]/div/ul/li/div[3]/a').click()
time.sleep(3)
main_window = driver.current_window_handle
prospectus=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'투자설명서')]") #contains 'prospetus'
time.sleep(3)
found_p = False
for p in prospectus:
    p.click()
    main =driver.find_elements_by_id("ifrm")
    re =driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to.window(re)
    side_panel = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leftPanelWrap")
    while len(side_panel) == 0:
        driver.refresh()
        side_panel = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leftPanelWrap")
    main_info_pages = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("모집 또는 매출에 관한 일반사항")
    if len(main_info_pages) == 0:
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
        continue
    else:
        try:
            main_info_pages[0].click()
        except:
            return None
        time.sleep(3)
        iframes = driver.find_elements_by_id("ifrm")
        if len(iframes) > 0:
            iframe = iframes[0]
            driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        source = driver.page_source
        if '460' in source:
            found_p = True
            print("Found prospectus with 460")
            break
```

The prospectus on the top of the website is the following, series number is 461 on the top, but I want the website open the website contains '460'

```
https://dart.fss.or.kr/dsaf001/main.do?rcpNo=20220627000389
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: Doesnt your code crash cause you get prospectus then loop and click ? Dont you get some error DOM have been changed or some similar?

Answer (score 0):

Check this xpath if it work for you, it check if title contains 460

```
"//title[contains(text(), '460')]"
```